# button using MvcSiteMapProvider isn't working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, button

I have a button in my html that uses the MvcSiteMapProvider to navigate back on the application, it works fine in all browsers except for Internet Explorer. The code in the html button:

```
<div class="global-content">
    <div class="content-title">
        @if (MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode != MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.RootNode)
        {
            if (MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode != null)
            {
                <a id="btn-return" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-return" href="@MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Url" data-loading-text="...">
                    <div class="arrow-return"></div>
                </a>
            }
        }
        <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
        @RenderSection("legend", required: false)
    </div>
```

note that I am already using the required scripts:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="~/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src= "~/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The error happens eventually when I click the button to redirect to the ParentNode page and the button simply show the data-loading-text("...") and gets disabled. But visual studio doesn't especify any error, the application just continue to works normaly but with the button disabeld, any help?

Comment: So, you're referring to IE 8 specifically? Also, can you show the *generated markup* rather (or in addition to) than the source?

Comment: This is happening in IE 11 , and when the error happens the only thing that changes is that the button becomes disabled showing the data-loading-text("...") but the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: What error? Could you please post it here in your question. Also, resulting markup would be very helpful as well. I'm confident the html5shiv and respond scripts are unrelated to this issue.